# Duplicate push notifications in ios?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We've been using APNS on our app without much incident for some time now, and suddenly our users are reporting receiving the same push notification multiple times.
I've confirmed - tediously - that our servers are only sending the notification payloads to Apple once, and yet the notification produces 2 and sometimes 3 identical alerts.

Comment: Using the Google Java library? If so had similar problems. You can use some Python code - small bits found on web - to send test notifications to your device - and I'll bet you never get duplicates.

Comment: Its not easy for me to use Python at this stage. Is this issue already reported to Apple? i don't think that it may be the cause with Java library.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely to be an apple error. My point with Python or other scripting tool is you can test pushes yourself. I have never gotten duplicates in many years of testing single pushes using the Python script I found - using both dev and prod. push servers.